# In Python, use a method both as instance and class method

Tags: python

I'm writing a program which plays Tic Tac Toe and has various versions of `ComputerPlayer`, such as the `RandomPlayer` and `THandPlayer`:

```
class RandomPlayer(ComputerPlayer):
    def __init__(self, mark):
        super(RandomPlayer, self).__init__(mark=mark)

    def get_move(self, board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        if moves:   # If "moves" is not an empty list (as it would be if cat's game were reached)
            return moves[np.random.choice(len(moves))]    # Apply random select to the index, as otherwise it will be seen as a 2D array

class THandPlayer(ComputerPlayer):
    def __init__(self, mark):
        super(THandPlayer, self).__init__(mark=mark)

    def get_move(self, board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        if moves:   # If "moves" is not an empty list (as it would be if cat's game were reached)
            for move in moves:
                if board.get_next_board(move, self.mark).winner() == self.mark:                         # Make winning move (if possible)
                    return move
                elif board.get_next_board(move, self.opponent_mark).winner() == self.opponent_mark:     # Block opponent's winning move
                    return move
            else:
                # return moves[np.random.choice(len(moves))]        # This is a repetition of the code in RandomPlayer and is not DRY
                randomplayer = RandomPlayer(mark=self.mark)
                return randomplayer.get_move(board)
                # return RandomPlayer.get_move(board)         # This returns an error as "get_move" is an instance method
```

The `THandPlayer` also selects moves at random if no winning move can be made or an opponent's winning move blocked. Right now I am doing this by creating an instance of `RandomPlayer` and calling `get_move` on it. This could be made more succinct, however, if `get_move` could be made such that it can be interpreted both as a class method and an instance method. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

To simplify the question, suppose we have two classes, `RandomPlayer` and `OtherPlayer`, both which have an instance method `get_move`:

```
import numpy as np

class RandomPlayer:
    def get_move(self, arr):
        return np.random.choice(arr)

class OtherPlayer:
    def get_move(self, arr):
        if max(arr) > 5:
            return max(arr)
        else:
            randomplayer=RandomPlayer()
            return randomplayer.get_move(arr)

arr = np.arange(4)

otherplayer = OtherPlayer()
print otherplayer.get_move(arr)
```

Is it possible to use `RandomPlayer`'s `get_move` method in `OtherPlayer` without creating an instance of `RandomPlayer`?

Comment: Instance methods have access to an instance (`self`), class or static methods do not. Either your method needs `self` or it does not. If it requires `self`, then it cannot be a class method or static. If it does not need `self`, then just make it a static/class method, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#staticmethod), which has access to neither `cls` nor `self` but can be accessed via either:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @staticmethod
...     def bar():
...         print('baz')
...         
>>> Foo.bar()
baz
>>> Foo().bar()
baz
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not noticed at first that you had omitted the `self` when defining the static method.

Answer (score 1):

A random move is a specific type of move; put a method which generates one in `ComputerPlayer`; then both `RandomPlayer` and `THandPlayer` can call it as necessary.

```
class ComputerPlayer(...):
    @staticmethod
    def choose_random_move(moves):
        if moves:
            return moves[np.random.choice(len(moves))]


class RandomPlayer(ComputerPlayer):    
    def get_move(self, board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        if moves:
            return self.choose_random_move(moves)


class THandPlayer(ComputerPlayer):

    def get_move(self, board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        for move in moves:
            for mark in [self.mark, self.opponent_mark]:
                if board.get_next_board(move, mark).winner() == mark:
                    return move
        else:
            return self.choose_random_move(moves)
```

Some extra notes:

- If your `__init__` method doesn't do anything except call `super` and pass along the exact same arguments, don't implement it; just let the inherited method be called directly.
- The two checks for a winner can be refactored.
- `choose_random_move` doesn't necessarily need to be a static method; you can keep it as an instance method with a default implementation that ignores any player-specific information in choosing a move. Derived classes can override the method if they like.

Comment: Regarding your last point, you actually _do_ want to make the move that would allow the opponent to win, as it blocks the square that the opponent could otherwise make its winning move in. (`move` here is a tuple representing a coordinate on the board that the player places its own mark on; I admit there may be some context missing from the question).

Comment: True; depending on the rules of the game, it could also be possible to block the move without actually making *that* exact move. But, strategy isn't really relevant to the question of making a random move, so I'll delete that discussion from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

(This is an alternative to my other answer, using a different abstraction.)

A random move isn't something associated with a player as much as it is something associated with a board; it's like `board.available_moves`, but returns a single move instead of all moves.

```
 class Board(...):
     # Given how often this is called by or before
     # random_move(), it would be smart to implement
     # some kind of caching so that the available
     # moves don't have to be recalcuated for the same board
     # state every time it is called.
     def available_moves(self):
         ...

     def random_move(self):
         moves = self.available_moves()
         if moves:
             return moves[np.random.choice(len(moves))]

class RandomPlayer(ComputerPlayer):

    def get_move(self, board):
        return board.random_move()

class THandPlayer(ComputerPlayer):
    def get_move(self, board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        if moves:
            for move in moves:
                if board.get_next_board(move, self.mark).winner() == self.mark:
                    return move
                elif board.get_next_board(move, self.opponent_mark).winner() == self.opponent_mark:
                    return move
            else:
                return board.random_move()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is my implementation of the solution suggested by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), in which I also followed [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s suggestion to refactor the two Boolean statements:

```
class RandomPlayer(ComputerPlayer):
    def __init__(self, mark):
        super(RandomPlayer, self).__init__(mark=mark)

    @staticmethod
    def get_move(board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        if moves:   # If "moves" is not an empty list (as it would be if cat's game were reached)
            return moves[np.random.choice(len(moves))]    # Apply random selection to the index, as otherwise it will be seen as a 2D array

class THandPlayer(ComputerPlayer):
    def __init__(self, mark):
        super(THandPlayer, self).__init__(mark=mark)

    def get_move(self, board):
        moves = board.available_moves()
        if moves:
            for move in moves:
                if THandPlayer.next_move_winner(board, move, self.mark):
                    return move
                elif THandPlayer.next_move_winner(board, move, self.opponent_mark):
                    return move
            else:
                return RandomPlayer.get_move(board)         

    @staticmethod
    def next_move_winner(board, move, mark):
        return board.get_next_board(move, mark).winner() == mark
```

A static method is used both to default to the random player and to refactor the Boolean statements.